# Programming languages that used degrees in trig functions?

Tags: programming, logo-language

Most programming languages that feature mathematical functions expect the arguments to be in radians. For example, `sin(1)` would typically return 0.841471, equivalent to sin 57.295°. But a couple of older languages didn't follow this convention:

- [Logo](https://el.media.mit.edu/logo-foundation/index.html) (1967): `sin 1` returns “You don't say what to do with 0.0174524058”
- [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) (1982): `1 sin` leaves the value of 0.0174524058 on the stack

Are there others that work directly specifying only degrees?

(For greater clarity: [OpenSCAD](https://openscad.org/) (2010) specifies degrees, but is still in active development. [Berkeley Logo](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebh/logo.html) also added functions such as `radsin` to allow use of radians. The HP-35 calculator only worked in degrees, but is not a programming language.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146777/discussion-on-question-by-scruss-programming-languages-that-used-degrees-in-trig); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 9):

The **Atari BASIC** (c) 1978, 1979, 1983 that came with the Atari 600 XL homecomputer had the `DEG` and `RAD` statements that not only decided upon the unit on input to `SIN` and `COS`, but also the unit on output from `ATN`.
Internally to BASIC, the use of Polynomial Evaluation meant degrees could stay degrees, and radians could stay radians. eg. For `SIN` and `COS`, they first divide the input by 90 (`DEG`) or pi/2 (`RAD`). Then they use the quotient mod 4 to establish the quadrant which will enable them to adjust the sine that they calculate using Polynomial Evaluation. All of this uses assembly everywhere which undoubtedly is fastest.
Had the `DEG` statement not been available, the user that would have preferred working from degrees, would have had to use costly multiplications by pi/180 or 180/pi to convert into or out-of radians. This would have been important in the space-cramped 6502 environment.

In my school we did learn about radians, but we exclusively used degrees. I was very happy that once I had bought the Atari 600 XL, I could just issue a one-time `DEG` statement and keep working in the comfort of degrees instead of having to use radians.

My next Atari computer was the 1040ST with the 68000 CPU inside. It came with the **Atari ST BASIC** (c) 1987. The `DEG` and `RAD` statements had gone. Just like any other programming language that I've seen from then on it exclusively worked with radians for its `COS`, `SIN`, `TAN`, and `ATN` functions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does sin(1800) when in degrees mode?  How about sin(31.4159265359) when in radians mode?

Comment: @supercat I guess that would not have been a problem. From the source code I just glimpsed, I see the first operation they do is dividing the input by 90 (`DEG`) or pi/2 (`RAD`). They then use the quotient mod 4 to establish the quadrant which enables them to adjust the `SIN` that they calculate.

Comment: When using degrees, is the input ever converted to radians, or does it simply work with the quarter-circle units that resulted from that first division you mentioned?

Comment: @supercat The sine is computed as a polynomial in quarter circle units. Since this polynomial is close to sin(pi/2 x), pi makes an appearance of sorts in the coefficients.

Comment: @supercat Degrees are not really converted to radians. Like WimC wrote above, they use Polynomial Evaluation.

Answer (score 7):

BASIC-G v2.0 for the [PMD 85-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMD_85) contains commands `DEG` and `RAD` that switch the mode between radians (the default) and degrees for the functions `SIN`, `COS` and `TANG`. This was a new feature of the v2.0 over the previous BASIC-G v1.0 for the PMD 85-1.

Comment: so if you wrote a programme in BASIC-G 2.0 assuming radians, but then added a line at the top calling `DEG`, it would give wrong results?

Comment: @scruss Exactly. Using stateful commands is fun, especially in combination with `GOSUB`s and similar, when you cannot guarantee  the program executed the switch or not (thus putting `DEG` at the very first line is actually the best option)

Answer (score 6):

Several BASIC dialects have the option to set the input unit for trigonometric functions. Sharp Pocket Computer BASIC have 2 means to set the input. Either by the setting button DEG/RAD/GRAD or by the BASIC keywords DEGREE, RADIAN and GRAD. On CASIO pocket computer a similar system exists. Either a settings button or the MODE keyword with option (4/5/6 for the FX-702P p.ex.).

Comment: but they still have the capability of working in radians, which PostScript and pre-UCB Logo do not

Answer (score 5):

Garry Kitchen's Gamemaker supported specifying a sprite movement direction as a value between 0 and 255; presumably this then used a lookup table for the cos/sin (dx/dy) values, possibly with some smarts to exploit symmetry etc. to make the table smaller, the point being this is one example where the language used neither degrees nor radians for trig-like things as was noted in a now-deleted comment.

Comment: The trig libraries in Super Mario 64, and countless other games as well, use the same units.  While scenarios where radians are the best scaling factor may be more common than those where degrees or grads are the best, units of whole resolutions are for many applications better yet.

Comment: These are brads, not degrees

Comment: @scruss: The question could sensibly be viewed more broadly as "anything other than [bleep]ing radians", which are an inferior choice for most actions which involve geometry, bordering on pants-on-head stupid for things like HTML5 canvas "rotate" (which is incapable of rotating the graphics transform by exactly 1/4 turn).

Comment: @supercat - but broadly dilutes the point. It's strange that HTML5 didn't inherit PostScript's use of degrees. `Math.PI / 2` is as close to a 1/4 turn as a canvas ever needs. All methods of angular representation have limits: my design work sometimes requires angles of 1/7 and 1/14 of a turn and none of degrees, radians, grads, brads or floating-point turns can represent them exactly

Comment: @scruss: At least when I tested it in Firefox some years back, an algorithm that repeatedly performed rotations by Math.PI/2 would start producing "horizontal" and "vertical" lines which weren't precisely horizontal and vertical.  A rotation by 90 degrees should yield a transform of precisely [0,1,-1,0,0,0] or [0,-1,1,0,0,0], depending upon direction, but a rotation by Math.PI/2 can't.

Answer (score -2):

This is a library feature: not a language feature.  None of the mainstream languages have built in trigonometry.  Some of the libraries just add a d to the end of the function name.

For instance, GNU Fortran, Intel Fortran and Matlab libraries have sind, cosd, tand and atan2d.

Comment: In some of the languages the OP mentioned in the question it _is in fact_ a _language_ feature, not a library feature, as the distinction between language and library is frequently not made in earlier languages.  In both Logo and Postscript, for example, the `sin` function shown by the OP is _built-in_ to the language, not considered part of a _library_ or _framework_ like we talk about them now.

Comment: Interestingly, the Algol 60 *Revised Report* merely says there should be a function sin(E) but does not explicitly specify the units of the argument E :-)  Unless one is supposed to infer radians from the wording 'the standard functions of analysis'.

Comment: even then, Fortran has always had built-in trig functions as part of the language